# What are the mechanisms to remove a question from the close queue?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, review-tools

I am interested in understanding better what it needs for a question to be removed from the close queue for good, apart from the obvious closing or deleting it. I have heard about several things vaguely but I do not understand it wll enough. For example

1. Close votes seem to have a finite lifetime, such that they can decay and do nothing in the end
2. A moderator is probaly able to remove questions from the close queue ?
3. I guess "leave open" statements and "close" statements somehow counteract each other. Do they exactly balance each other, such that 1 "leave open" statement annihilates 1 "close" statement? If the number of "close" statements equals the number of "leave open" statements, does the question then get removed from the close queue? And related, what happens if a question has 5 "close" statments and say 3 "leave open" statements, does it then get closed? I think it should not, because the "close" and "leave open" statements should have equal weight?

Generally, what are the mechanisms that can remove a question from the close queue?

BTW the same question(s) could be asked concerning the reopen queue, what removes question from it, how the "reopen" and "leave closed" statements counteract each other there, etc

Comment: Better ask on main meta . [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Dilaton, are you questions answered by http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/2509 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/2509? Those should cover most of it.

Comment: Thanks @dmckee those look good, I will study them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Close votes can [age away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away), at which point the voter won't be able to VTC on the same question again...
2. Moderators can remove questions from the queue by closing them or selecting "Leave Open". In the latter case, the outstanding close votes remain on the question until the question is closed or the votes age away (see #1).
3. If a certain number (currently three) of "Leave Open" responses are garnered in review, the question is removed from the queue without being closed, and the outstanding close votes become eligible for aging as described in #1. A given question will be dequeued as soon as it receives *either* 3 "Leave Open" responses or 5 "Close" votes. Since close votes are not immediately deleted, it is possible for a question to be dequeued via Leave Open responses and then closed anyway.

Questions will be removed from the queue if a reviewer opts to edit them. Questions can also be removed from the queue if a bounty is added, if they are locked, or if they are deleted.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-button-leave-open-previously-do-not-close